# Trying to get the HTML from a page after I submit some data

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Having enormous trouble getting the new html document after submitting on the first page. The new page has a different url, but can't be directly navigated to since it's not unique. Even though this gets ie to the new page, I can't get VBA to find the new url or document. I've tried putting breakpoints and waiting for it to load, it doesn't seem to be the problem. Is there something strange about this website that i'm not accounting for? **Other people seem to be getting success when they run the same code, where could this problem lie?**

```
   Sub Macro1()

    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLinputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/prc6.cgi?
    &ms_user=monm&passwd=&srch_type=0&adv=0&out_type=0&district=1421"

    Do 'Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)


    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

    Dim CurrentElement As HTMLInputElement

    ' filling in the forms and submitting
    Dim els As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set els = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("p_loc")
    Set CurrentElement = els(0)
    CurrentElement.Value = "11 michelle"
    Set HTMLinputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    HTMLinputs(7).Click 

    ' Waiting for new page to load...
    Do 'Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
    Debug.Print ie.document.URL

    ' Printing the contents of the table (should be the table on the results 
    page)
    Dim tbl
    Set tbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
    Dim tableText
    tableText = tbl.innerText
    Debug.Print tableText

End Sub
```

My immediate window prints this:
http://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/prc6.cgi?&ms_user=monm&passwd=&srch_type=0&adv=0&out_type=0&district=1421

Assessment Records Search

Step 1: Select Database: Current Owners/Assmt List Deed/Sr1a List
Step 2: Select County: ATLANTIC BERGEN BURLINGTON CAMDEN CAPE MAY CUMBERLAND ESSEX GLOUCESTER HUDSON HUNTERDON **...et cetera**

When it should be printing the contents of the results page.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling click on the correct input?

Comment: Does `HTMLinputs(7).Click` need to be `HTMLinputs(7).Click()`

Comment: It's getting me to the correct page so it must be correct right? It's just that VBA is still grabbing the old page's html.  The IE window is showing the correct page.

Comment: This submits from local PC fine:  <form method=post action="http://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/inf.cgi"><input type="submit" value="submit" /><input name="ms_user" value="monm" /><input name="passwd" value="" /><input name="srch_type" value="1" /> <input name="select_cc" value="1401" /><input name="district" value="1421" /><input name="adv" value="1" /><input name="out_type" value="1" /><input name="ms_ln" value="50" /><input name="p_loc" value="11 michelle" /><input name="owner" value="" /><input name="block" value="" /><input name="lot" value="" /><input name="qual" value="" /></form>

Comment: @Dy.Lee Can you elaborate on this? I've tried putting application.wait after READYSTATE_COMPLETEs, so the page is loading in time for the code that works on it.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins How can I use that to fix my code?

Comment: @JakeG:  may be, I have mistaked.

Comment: Jake, see my answer. Before I got your code working I was thinking about having you write that HTML to your HTMLdocument and then clicking that submit button. To @Dy.Lee's point READYSTATE_COMPLETE is nothing. so you after clicking submit the wait loop continued for ever.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues in your code:

`READYSTATE_COMPLETE` was not defined. Change it `4`

I was getting errors defining `CurrentElement as CurrentElement`. Changing it to `HTMLInputElement` made that error go away.

The input you are trying to set `p_loc` has the name attribute set not id, so `HTMLDoc.getElementById("p_loc")` was nothing.

To fix, set CurrentElement to `HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("p_loc")(0)`

With these changes the following code works:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLinputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/prc6.cgi?&ms_user=monm&passwd=&srch_type=0&adv=0&out_type=0&district=1421"

    Do 'Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)


    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

    Dim CurrentElement As HTMLInputElement

    Dim els As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set els = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("p_loc")
    Set CurrentElement = els(0)
    CurrentElement.Value = "11 michelle"
    Set HTMLinputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    HTMLinputs(7).Click

    Do 'Until .readyState = 4
         DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
    Debug.Print ie.document.URL
    Debug.Print HTMLDoc.body.innerText
End Sub
```

[image]

Since your most likely going to want the table from the results page:

You can easily get it like this:

```
Dim tbl
Set tbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
Dim tableText
tableText = tbl.innerText
```

Once you have the table reference you can parse the data to your liking.

[image]

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: This code runs, but is it giving you the html of the page after submit or the initial page? my immediate window is still showing the body of the first page.

Comment: It is, attached screen shot.

Comment: Yes, it has navigated to the right web page. But the debugger, it should output that web page's html, it's not.

Comment: The code is getting **`innerText`** not the **`innerHTML`**, If you want the html you can change that. Look at the  Yellow tool tip above the break point. It shows `Search Results 1 records found for Di....` If you view source on the results page you'll see a hidden _<title>Search Results</title>_ tag and obviously the page says **1 record found for district: ...**

Comment: I just added another screen shot and additional code to get the table from the results page.

Comment: Everything seems like it should work, but do you see how it's giving me the table from the initial page in the immediate, not the results page? http://i.imgur.com/rMqt2Hi.png

Comment: That table is from the results page. The text from the table from the results page is  "B Block Lot Qual Class Location Owner 
More Info 163.2 14   2 11 MICHELLE WAY STEIN, SUSAN" This the same thing being shown in the screen shot tool tip of the results page table and in the value of the watch window in the screen shot

Comment: Did you click on the screenshot? It's outputting the table from the first page.  i.imgur.com/rMqt2Hi.png

Comment: I am not getting that, see my intermediate window.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Why am I not getting your output? I think we have identical code.

Comment: Copy my entire code, from sub macro1 to end sub and run it. You might have missed something. Try also putting a break point while you run the debugger.

Comment: Copied it all and ran it with the breakpoint. Same thing. Also not seeing the tooltip you're getting. Where do you think this problem is?

Comment: IDK, update your question with your complete code and your intermediary log. Also, add a few Debug.Print statements to indicate what is being printed out where in your code.